Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility.Contracts, Version=17.10.2083.0' or one of its dependencies
After upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 Pro 17.10, a custom add-in is triggering the following error. However, we couldn't find this version of the assembly or what it is referring to.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility.Contracts, Version=17.10.2083.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The latest version on Nuget is 17.10.2079.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Extensibility.Contracts/17.10.2079
I tried to upgrade all Nuget Packages and rebuild the add-in without success.
Any idea how to solve this?
